# Select an object based on the value of another object in jq

Tags: json, jq

Given the following (simplified) JSON.

```json
{
  "buildsByBranchName": {
    "origin/master": { "buildNumber": 28694 },
    "master": { "buildNumber": 28563 },
    "refs/remotes/origin/master": { "buildNumber": 4094 }
  },
  "lastBuiltRevision": {
    "branch": [
      { "name": "origin/master" }
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to find the build number of the last branch that was built.

The logic to do so is to find the name of the branch `.lastBuiltRevision.branch[0].name` = `origin/master`. Then use the branch name to find the build number `.buildsByBranchName | to_entries[] | select(."key" == "origin/master") .value.buildNumber` = `28694`. But I don't know how to combine them.

After `.buildsByBranchName` I have no access to `lastBuiltRevision` in my select. Or is there any way?

I can probably do this with two calls to jq. But I'd really like to do this with only one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need for `select()`, you can use the branch as the desired key in `buildByBranchName`:

```
.buildsByBranchName[.lastBuiltRevision.branch[0].name].buildNumber
```

Output: `28694`

---

Should you need to use the `.lastBuiltRevision.branch[0].name` on more places, consider setting a variable:

```
.lastBuiltRevision.branch[0].name as $branch | .buildsByBranchName[$branch].buildNumber
```